# User Gets Routed to Log In Screen After Registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller

**Context**:

When a user registers, I want them to be routed to a specific Create page based on the role they select [Employer, Student, Teacher]. The goal being is that they create their role-profile as soon as they finish registering.

When I first wrote the code, it worked- but this was prior to me adding Authorization to each controller. Now when they Register, they get routed back to the log-in page. They also can't access their Role-Authorized areas. It's only when the user logs out and logs back in can they get to where they should go.

The code I'm sharing is just for the Employer section of the app, but it applies to all areas where Authorization is in the Controller.

## The Code

### Account Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.UserRoles);
                    var roles= await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
                    if (roles.Contains("Student"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Students", new { area = "Students" });
                    }

                    else if (roles.Contains("Employer"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Employers", new { area = "Employers" });
                    }
                    else if (roles.Contains("Faculty"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Faculties", new { area = "Teachers" });
                    }
                    else
                    { return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); }
                   
                }
                ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.Where(u => !u.Name.Contains("Admin"))
                                 .ToList(), "Name", "Name");
                AddErrors(result);
            }

           
            return View(model);
        }
```

### Employer Controller

I applied the Authorization over the whole controller, rather than individual aspects- since no other user than Admin or the assigned Role should be able to access that. I felt like that was the best and easiest way to apply that. I redacted the rest of the code, since the issue most likely exists with the Authorization

```
 namespace InTurn.Areas.Employers.Controllers
    {
       [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Employer")]
        public class EmployersController : Controller
        {
            .
            .
            .
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this Core or .Net?

Comment: This is built in .Net.

Comment: You can add something as simple as Identity or something more robust like OpenID Connect

Comment: Sorry-

I'm not sure I completely understand. This is only my second time working with MVC, and only my 1st time building an app from scratch.